# Adding inertia for WPF touch application listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, touch

I have a full screen WPF application built for a touch monitor, and I have some ListBoxes on the main screen.

When I flick the `Listbox` it scrolls fine, but when it gets to the end of the list, the entire application gets pulled down from the top of the screen, But I need the inertia just for the list box not for the entire window. How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **ManipulationBoundaryFeedback** event enables applications or
>   components to provide visual feedback when an object hits a boundary.
>   For example, the Window class handles the ManipulationBoundaryFeedback
>   event to cause the window to slightly move when its edge is
>   encountered.

So, a way around it is to handle ManipulationBoundaryFeedback on the ListBox, and set Handled to true:

```
<ListBox ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback">            
  // ...
</ListBox>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback(object sender, ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled  = true;
}
```

Comment: This will only solve the flickering.. I need the Listbox to move inertially

Comment: did you also implemented `InertiaProcessor Attached Dependency Property`

Comment: no.. How to add that one?Can you please help me in adding that?

Comment: This might be a good example for inertia [Friction Scrolling Now An WPF Attached Behaviour Too](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48871/Friction-Scrolling-Now-An-WPF-Attached-Behaviour-T)